# Sci-fi short story about a young brother and sister with a crystal hologram room which parents want to get rid of

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a sci-fi short story that was assigned to my class in middle school (around 2005), but was presumably written in the latter half of the 20th century. I am not sure if it was completely age-appropriate.

The plot revolves around a brother (max age 12) and his sister (max age 8), who have a playroom walled with crystals that can recreate any environment they imagine. The room is very good at what it does - think Proust's strong emotional reaction to smells, but with all senses. The parents of the children are having second thoughts on having the crystal room in their house, especially as it seems to be the only place the children want to play, and are planning to get rid of it. The children are very against this idea.

Although the parents have had a bad feeling about the room and its effect on their children's development for a while, when both they and the children enter the room, it is implied that the little sister changes the the environment to a serene scene of the Swiss Alps, and the parents know this, with both the calm emanating from the room and this fact placating their fears. However, the next day, the father's wallet goes missing somewhere in the house, and when his search leads him the the playroom, he finds himself in a oppressively hot savanna, with groups of hungry lions in the near distance. It is implied that this is a trap that the children set to kill their parents. Whether the lions are tangible or holograms are uncertain, as is the mode of murder.

The last scene is of an adult neighbor or family friend visiting the house, and the children are happily having a tea party outside. They are asked where their parents are, but I cannot remember their reply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are thinking of “[The Veldt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veldt_(short_story))” by Ray Bradbury.

The children become fixated on “the nursery", a sort of holodeck-type room that can reproduce any scene they imagine.

They keep returning to a scene on the African veldt with lions devouring their prey. Disturbed, the parents call in a psychologist who urges them to abandon their home and move into the country.

The children beg to use the nursery for one last time before they leave, and lock their parents in the room with the scene set to the veldt. The psychologist comes by later to look for the parents, and finds the children eating lunch in the nursery, and it is implied that the lions are now devouring the bodies of the parents in the distance.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed "The Veldt" by Ray Bradbury.